# Querying topic types in C++

Tags: ros, c++, roscpp, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I there a way in C++ to query if a topic exists and if so what message type it uses?

I am trying to write a generic visualization tool and would like to subscribe to a topic using a callback matching the topic's type.

Alternatively a method that accepts all messages but allows me to learn their type in the callback would also work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29660/querying-topic-types-in-c++/) by [Matt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1965/matt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [xmlrpc api](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Master_API) should be able to do that. (getPublishedTopics)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1